# Best design pattern for building PC objects?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am building a application for an assignment that allows the user to build a personal computer and view the price of the computer. For example, the user should be able to choose a CPU, a graphics card and a hard drive. What's the best design pattern to use for this application? I thought about using the decorator pattern but I'm not really sure that that's the best choice because it's not a creational pattern.

Comment: Design patterns are tools to apply with thought, not apply as a rule.

Comment: definitely not decorator. a pc is not a type of hard drive, or the other way around. classic composition

Comment: So... Go with simple composition instead of a pattern?

Comment: This looks a lot like you having a homework question that requires you to do that with a design pattern. For such a simple thing, using a DP is overkill. Without context, I can't think of a reason to recommend any one of GoF's patterns at all, and suggest you go for simpler designs.

Comment: It does not require that I use a design pattern.. I'm trying to use one because I thought that they lead to cleaner code.

Comment: @mahela007 they make complex software easier to build and maintain, for sure, but they do add their own complexity to it. I am going to make a really high level analogy: the GoF's design patterns are like vital organs. They integrate with the body they are part of, and make sure it works efficiently enough to live. A complex organism needs those in order to be viable. Follow me so far? Well, the challenge you're trying to solve is a bacteria, and microbes don't need hearts, lungs or stomachs ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you only need an object.  A `PC`, this `PC` object contains a `Motherboard` object which defines how many `input` output `ports` it has, what type of processor fits.  Then you just plug processor objects into `setProcessor(processorA)`, expansion cards, etc, etc...

To get the price you just have a `toPrice()` on the `PC` which calculates everything connected to it.  Actually a seperate pricing object would be better that you hand the `PC` to, the pricing object just asks the `PC` to list it's components and calculates them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're building, you might consider a [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) design pattern?